# How do I turn off DST (Daylight Saving Time)?

Tags: server, time

How do I turn off DST (Daylight Saving Time)?

Iran has abandoned DST altogether, but old Ubuntus still think DST is needed. I want to turn off DST and fix the timezone on `+0330`.

I like to do this with a noninteractive command.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 2):

There's a good (and lengthy) two-part discussion on Iran's abolishment of DST and its implications for various aspects of OS time services over on this [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/693876/60677) thread. Worth reviewing for your particular issue.